# Spring Oauth2 Modify response on Invalid Token Exception

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-oauth2

My application uses Spring Security Oauth2 with JWTToken.

I'm trying to modify the body of the response when it returns the error 401, which happens when an unauthenticated user tries to access data:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Cannot convert access token to JSON"
}
```

To do this, I implemented my own `WebResponseExceptionTranslator` and I set it in my Authentification Entry Point like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint () {
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        authenticationEntryPoint.setExceptionTranslator(new CustomWebResponseExceptionTranslator());
        return authenticationEntryPoint;
    }
}
```

However, it continues to use the default `WebResponseExceptionTranslator`. So, my question is, how can I force him to use mine?

Answer (score 0):

If you used `WebResponseExceptionTranslator`, you should put it in `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter));
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
            .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .exceptionTranslator(webResponseExceptionTranslator());
```